# How to get the checkbox clicked using selenium, python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, checkbox, webdriverwait

Can't get the checkbox clicked using python selenium, geckodriver.

The input line in the following html (from inspect-element option) appears grey in color and does not highlight the checkbox.

```
<div class="ui_checkbox BZGrt w">
 <input id="checkbox_590" type="checkbox" class="input" value="10697">
 <label class="label" for="checkbox_590" >
  ::before
  <div class="icWwC f u k w"><span class="PDJtN"><span class="mTKbF">Vegan Options</span></span></div></label></div>
```

The checkbox is highlighted when cursor is over `::before`

My python code is the following:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

#link = link_list[0]
link = "https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Restaurants-g186338-London_England.html"
driver = webdriver.Firefox() 
time.sleep(2)
driver.get(link)
WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'onetrust-accept-btn-handler'))).click()
driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="checkbox_590"]').click()
```

Please help with getting that checkbox clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You can find by for of label, it is not the best but i try it works.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

#link = link_list[0]
link = "https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Restaurants-g186338-London_England.html"
driver = webdriver.Firefox() 
time.sleep(2)
driver.get(link)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//label[@for='checkbox_590']").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

To click on the [checkbox](/questions/tagged/checkbox) associated with the `<label>` ***Vegan Options*** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use the following [*locator strategy*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Restaurants-g186338-London_England.html")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//span[text()="Vegan Options"]//ancestor::label[1]'))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: Vegan Options]